# Using image morphological techniques, locate the broken locations

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-morphology

Can someone please guide the steps/the operation to be performed to construct this image and detect the broken fence position of the Image.

[image]

1. Thresholding the image to a binary image : to convert the input image to a binary image
2. Inverting the image : inverting it to get a black background and white lines
3. Dilation with SE one unit of the fence structure
4. Apply Erosion
5. Bitwise-and masks together: retrieve the original back- and foreground the image is inverted by subtracting the bitwise_or from 255
6. Constructed Image - Original Image will give us the position of the broken fence

Will this solution work ?

Comment: Did you try it? This is the nice thing about image processing, you can very easily try your idea and see if it works.

Comment: to detect defects in an instance of a pattern, you have to recognize the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you call locate.

After large horizontal erosion and binarization:

[image]